# What is the best way to locate a Cave Spider spawner?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

What is the best way to find a cave spider spawner, using it's spawning ideals such as biomes, coordinates, or natural terrain, if it has any.

Comment: Let me add biome: Mesa/badlands, is where mineshafts are abundant, spawn up to the surface, poke out sides of mountains or carve into surface, and it's not uncommon to find a cave spider spawner right on the surface, where a corridor generation carves through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawner#Natural_generation), monster spawners can be naturally generated in the following locations:

- Dungeons
- Mineshafts
- Woodland mansions
- Strongholds
- Nether fortresses
- Bastion remnants

Of these locations, only those generated in mineshafts will naturally spawn cave spiders:

> Any number of cave spider spawners, densely surrounded by cobwebs, scattered throughout.

Finding them in these locations is also defined in the above block quote.

Comment: Spiders are not cave spiders; they are explicitly different, as one poisons the player while the other does not.

Comment: @Corsaka thank you for pointing out the nomenclature issue in my answer. Updating it now.

Answer (score 6):

Cave Spiders spawners are found in the Abandoned Mineshafts underground. The spawners can be specifically located by cobweb-rich shafts, such as the one below.

[image: cave spiders]

Answer (score 5):

From [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Badlands)

> Mineshafts generate at much higher elevations in these [badlands] biomes, often exposed to fresh air.

Cave spider spawners are only present in mineshafts, and while mineshafts don't generate any more *commonly* in any particular biome, they can generate at much higher altitudes in badlands, to the point where you can often simply wander the surface of a badlands and stumble upon an exposed mineshaft.

So if your goal is to quickly find a cave spider spawner, find a badlands and start looking through the nearest mineshafts. Minimal digging required.

Comment: Good one, even if badlands are a pretty rare biome. I wanted to post the same answer, so +1